# Can twilio Programmable voice be integrated with Google's DialogFlow?

Tags: twilio, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, dialogflow-es, voice

Is there a way to route a voice call to google Dialogflow (or Amazon Lex) ?

sequence:

1. Call comes into to a number
2. Twilio sends the voice input to endpoint (DialogFlow)
3. Text response is received from DialogFlow
4. Twilio streams voice (text to speech) back to caller

Note: This can be achieved using Google telephony. However, I would like to know if this is possible by using the twilio at the call handling layer ?

Comment: Twilio evangelist, thanks for the reply, but I am in Brazil, and in Brazilian Portuguese, google works better to synthesize the voice and also to transcript to text... so I repeat the initial question: There is a way to integrate twilio calls but using google voice engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could do this using [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) with [`input="speech"`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#input) to transcribe the caller's speech to text. When the live transcription is complete, Twilio makes a webhook request to the `action` attribute for the `<Gather>` with the `SpeechResult` as one of the parameters.

You can then send that text to the service you want to use (Dialogflow/Lex), which will respond with the response which you can then put into a [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say) element and respond to the webhook to speak the response.

If you're interested in building automated response bots like this, you might want to look into [Twilio Autopilot](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot) which has the speech to text and NLP built in for phone calls and can also be used across messaging platforms and Alexa too.